# Limit maximum GPS between 2 distances

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have read many articles similar to this, but I didn't get answers I need:

So, I have an application connected to my back-end server, like onSite Attendance where users (technicians in this case) go to certain places and do documentations there using photo features where it has automatic watermark feature (showing coordinates and distance to site),

I set a coordinate where users have to visit and take pictures, but I want to limit distance to site, so if users take pictures more than 100 metres tolerance to site, the app automatically close,

Currently I am using both Java and Kotlin for development,

How can I achieve this?

This is the code for getting location:

```
class LocationService(context: Context): LiveData<Result<Throwable, Location?>>() {

    private var fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

    override fun onInactive() { // is called when the lifecycle owner(LocationActivity) is either paused, stopped or destroyed
        super.onInactive()
        fusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback)
    }

    override fun onActive() { // is called when the lifecycle owner(LocationActivity) is either started or resumed
        super.onActive()
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { setLocationData(it) }
            .addOnFailureListener {t -> setErrorData(t) }

        startLocationUpdates()
    }

    private fun setLocationData(location: Location?) { // location is nullable as if GPS is turned off even if the last
                                                        // location was previously retrieve because disabling location clears the cache
        //value = LocationEvent.OnLocationResult(Result.build { location })
        value = Result.build { location }
    }

    private fun setErrorData(t: Throwable) {
        //value = LocationEvent.OnLocationResult(Result.build { throw t })
        value = Result.build { throw t }
    }

    private fun startLocationUpdates() {
        Timber.d { "start location updates" }
        fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,
            locationCallback,
            null // looper
        )
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Android **Geofencing**

Geofencing combines awareness of the user's current location with awareness of the user's proximity to locations that may be of interest. To mark a location of interest, you specify its latitude and longitude. To adjust the proximity for the location, you add a radius. The latitude, longitude, and radius define a geofence, creating a circular area, or fence, around the location of interest.

You can have multiple active geofences, with a limit of 100 per app, per device user. For each geofence, you can ask Location Services to send you entrance and exit events, or you can specify a duration within the geofence area to wait, or dwell, before triggering an event. You can limit the duration of any geofence by specifying an expiration duration in milliseconds. After the geofence expires, Location Services automatically removes it. [more](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing)